# Ruby on rails session = nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, null

In a controller I have 2 actions

```
def action1
  session[:test]="test"
  render :text => session[:test]  # output test
end

def action2
  render :text => session[:test]  # output nil
end
```

I perform first action1 so the session is set
Then I perform action2 but session[:test] is nil

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of session store are you using?  `ActionController::Base.session_store`

Comment: I'm using active_record_store

Comment: Why are you using active_record_store?  Is there a reason.  You get so much for free with the cookie_store.

Answer (score 1):

**Cookies enabled?**
Assuming you are using the default cookie-based session_store, make sure you have cookies enabled while testing.

**Schema in place?** 
An activerecord session_store requires a `sessions` table with the correct columns (id, session_id, data) [More info](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SessionStore.html).

Comment: The schema is in place, actually it seems that the session is set only the first I initialize it.
When I make a modification the session value do not update.
is there anything else to do than :
session[:test]="test"
session[:test]="test2"